# Orthogonal Projections on Polyhedral Cones

Tags: geometry, projection, convex-cone

Suppose there are two distinct tetrahedral cones in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with vertices at the origin. Each cone is formed by three rays emanating from the origin.

(i) Is it possible to project (orthogonally) onto some face of at least one cone from any point outside the cones ?

(ii) If so, how can you divide the space outside the given cones into further cones so that any point therein is projected onto some face of exactly one or both given cones ?

What geometrical features are required to characterize the above situations ?

Comment: I'm finding this question confusing and unclear. First, I'm assuming by "face", you're referring to the three $2$-dimensional faces? When you say the cones are "distinct", do you mean that they intersect only at the origin (e.g. would it be allowed for one cone to lie strictly inside the other)? If the answer to both questions is yes, then no, certain pairs of cones will have some points where both points of projection lie on edges or at the origin.

Comment: I agree with user837206. It looks like, unless for example the two cones are opposite octants, for example the first octant $x>0 \ \& \ y>0 \ \& \ z>0$ and the last one, your property will not be verified.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the 2-dimensional faces of the cones. Distinct cones mean they intersect only at the origin. One cone doesn't lie within the other.

Comment: Each side of a cone forms an angle and its interior. The points that project orthogonally onto that side for an infinite wedge. You have two cones with 3 sides each. That is six wedges. If your cones both have small angles, it is pretty obvious these wedges are not going to fill all of space, leaving plenty of points that will not be orthogonally projectible onto a side. If you allow orthogonal projections onto the edges from any direction, you also get six half-spaces. But again if the angles are small these need not fill space either.